# Rails - turbolinks issue after redirect

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks

I have some weird behavior after I changed my login form to "remote: true".
Before, after the login was successful I made a redirect_to to a different page, which execudes Javascript in the body.

```
<script>
writeCookie();
</script>
```

The Javascript is loaded via the view specific coffee file

```
#= require write_time_zone_cookie
```

writeCookie() works like expected, but after I change the login form to "remote: true" I get an JS error after the redirect_to.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: writeCookie is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:4:11)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:5227)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:4879)
    at Object.t.dispatch (turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:6)
    at r.t.Controller.r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:7)
    at r.t.Controller.r.visitCompleted (turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:7)
    at r.t.Visit.r.complete (turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:6)
    at r.<anonymous> (turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:6)
    at turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:6
```

I tried already some suggestions from the web like:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
          writeCookie();
        });
```

But this does not solve my problem.
Does someone have an idea?

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Can you post your entire javascript manifest file (application.js)?

Comment: @PatrickO'Grady

//= require turbolinks
//= require read_url_params

Answer (score 0):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: writeCookie is not defined
```

means that the `function writeCookie() {}` is not defined in your js file.

to prove this just include in your `<script>` tags the following function

```
<script>
   function writeCookie() {
      // Your function code hear
   }
   writeCookie();
</script>
```

If this solves your issue, I am right. You do not have the function, so the problem is connected with your asset pipeline.

The reason is that probably you are running that script in your html document, when the document is loaded, maybe before that the asset pipeline loads your file `write_time_zone_cookie` or `read_url_params` which includes the `writeCookie()` function.

All the files need to be included in your asset pipeline, so check in your browser developer tools if your file is loaded in the asset pipeline when you run that `writeCookie()` function. Just set a breakpoint.

I can help you more, but give us more information, it is not really possible to help you more with the limited info you gave us

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it ended up with deleting turbolinks completely ([Guide how to do it](http://codkal.com/rails-how-to-remove-turbolinks/)). I saw more JS issues after page-reloads and double controller action executions. It helps to "Preserve log" in the console :) . The only problem I faced afterwards was the redirect on AJAX calls. I solved by adding a helper method to my ApplicationController:

```
def redirect_by_request_type(url)
    if request.xhr?
      render js: "window.location='#{url}'"
    else
      redirect_to url, status: 303, turbolinks: false
    end
  end
```